# What number to expect when playing with uint16_t and bitwise ops

Tags: c++, c, bit-manipulation

I have this simple code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>

int main(void) {
    uint16_t i = 0;
    unsigned char *b = "Yh";
    i = b[1] | (b[0] << 8);
    printf("uint16_t: %u\n", i);
    return 0;
}
```

As you can see, I'm adding `Y (HEX: 0x59, DEC: 89)` and `h (HEX: 0x68, DEC: 104)` to a `uint16_t` with a bitwise operation.

The `Y` gets moved to the left 8 bits and the `h` is added at the end.
The final content of `i` should be `89 104`, right?

If I then print `i`, what number should I expect to come out?
I'm currently getting `22888` and I'm not sure why nor if that is what I should get.

Comment: Change `%u` become `%x` and you see everything is fine.

Comment: By the way, 'h' = 104 = 0x68, not 0x69.

Comment: Yup, typo. Will edit the question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

89 is now in the higher 8 bits, so it's 89*2<sup>8</sup>+104 = 22888.

In hexadecimal, it's more visible: you took 0x59, shifted it by 8 bits left which gave you 0x5900, and then added 0x68. 0x5968 = 22888.

Comment: Indeed. I don't know why I failed at seeing it this way. Thank you :)

Comment: `char` is 8 bit long only then how you deduced that `0x59` shifted to `0x5900`?

Comment: @haccks It got promoted, because I have a `uint16_t`.

Comment: @haccks I believe all arithmetic here is performed in 'int' (see 'Integral promotion' for C++) and then truncated to uint16_t.

Comment: @alexandernst It got promoted  to `int`, because that's how C++ works.  If instead of `0x59`, you had something like `0xE9`, for example, and put it in the low order bits, you might not find what you expected, because the `char` would be promoted to a (signed) `int`.  The conversion of the signed `int` to `uint16_t` doesn't occur until the actual assignment.

Comment: @JamesKanze Interesting. Can you suggest how to fix that?

Comment: @alexandernst The promotion occurs when the value is an operand to an arithmetic operation.  Converting it to `unsigned char` first will ensure that the value being promoted is in the range `0...UCHAR_MAX`.  Otherwise, what we did before there was `unsigned char` was to and it with `0xFF`; both work and are valid, and at least to me, equally readable (but maybe because I've seen both so much).

Comment: @JamesKanze So I'm safe if I do it the way I did it here? (b being an unsigned char)

Comment: @alexandernst Yes.  The range of an unsigned char never includes negative values.  (There is a very strong argument that a type designed to contain character codes should never be signed.  I've never seen an encoding that uses negative values.)

Answer (score 3):

Maybe with binary it's more clear what's going on.

So first `Y` -> `HEX: 0x59 DEC: 89` get's shifted 8 bits to the left:

```
0101 1001      = Y
0101 1001 << 8
--------------------
0101 1001 0000 0000 = (Y << 8)
```

After this a simple bitwise OR operator with `h` -> `HEX: 0x68 DEC: 104`

So:

```
0101 1001 0000 0000   = (Y << 8)
          0110 1000 | = h
---------------------
0101 1001 0110 1000 = 22888
```